# Adding array pointer in ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm

Say we have an array `X` of a type (4 bytes) and its base address is in `r0`. And we have a variable `y` that is in `r1` and a variable `z` in `r2`.

If we do this:

```
add r1, r0, r1
ldr r2, [r1]
```

What would it do? I know it's super simple but I'm not understanding how adding an array address and some constant would work. Also I don't understand the syntax of `ldr r2, [r1]`. I know it loads in `r2` but what is `[r1]`?

Is it all the elements of the array? So is `r2` now also a base address of an array that's a copy of `r1`? Did `r1` become an array when it got added to one? So is original `y` added to every element of the array? I'm basically asking how this would convert to function in C. Right now I am guessing `z = g*(B[0] + B[1] + B[2] + B[3])` but I'm not sure that makes any sense.

Comment: The brackets are part of ARM's syntax for memory operands.  They have no relationship to array indexing in C.  As a rule of thumb, in many assembly languages, `(foo)` or `[foo]` indicate the memory at address `foo`.  Refer to the manual of your assembler for details.

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this:

```
add r1, r0, r1 /* r1 = r0 + r1 */
ldr r2, [r1]   /* r2 = value at address in r1 */
```

those two lines are a translation of an array access `x[index]`.
In order to calculate the address of `x[index]` the assembly line `add r1, r0, r1` is generated, where `r0` is the base address of `x` (address of `x[0]`) and `r1` is `index` (multiplied by 4) so `r1` finally contains `x[index]` address. Then in order to fetch `x[index]` the assembly load it from the memory address calculated using the line `ldr r2, [r1]`.